# How to store output data of a function in a text file

Tags: c++, visual-c++-6

I have the following code

```
    if (StartMonitor) //StartMonitor
    {

        TotalVoltage5s += CalculatePower();
        //TotalVoltage5s += 20;
        xx123++;

        CString sad;
        m_power_edit.GetWindowText(sad);

        int num1 = _ttoi(sad);
        if(xx123 >= num1){
            if(TotalTime > 19){

                Power_Log_Chart.ClearChart();
                TotalTime = 0;
            }



            CTime tm;
            tm=CTime::GetCurrentTime();
            CString str=tm.Format("%X");
            ostringstream os;
            ostringstream os1;
            float ds= (float)atof((char *)(LPTSTR)(LPCTSTR)sad);
            os << TotalVoltage5s/ds;
            os1 << m_frequency;
            m_power_list.InsertColumn(Current_columns,"",LVCFMT_CENTER,80,0);
            m_power_list.SetItemText(0, Current_columns, str);
            m_power_list.SetItemText(1, Current_columns, os.str().c_str());
            m_power_list.SetItemText(2, Current_columns, os1.str().c_str());
            m_power_list.SetItemState(Current_columns, LVIS_SELECTED|LVIS_FOCUSED, LVIS_SELECTED|LVIS_FOCUSED);  
            m_power_list.EnsureVisible(Current_columns, FALSE);

            Power_Log_Chart.SetXYValue(TotalTime, TotalVoltage5s/ds, TotalTime, 0);
            TotalTime++;
            TotalVoltage5s = 0;
            m_frequency = 0; 
            xx123 = 0;

        }

    }
    Power_Log_Chart.Invalidate();
}
CDialog::OnTimer(nIDEvent);
```

}

What it simply does, it takes the output of the function CalculatePower and it plots and displays its results in real time every 5 seconds, and it does the same thing for frequency and  time.

I need a method to save the data in a text file and this is what i tried to do but i am not sure if it is going to work or not.

```
        SavePowerData[32780] =TotalVoltage5s; 
        SaveTimeData[32780] = TotalTime; 
         ofstream myfile;
         myfile.open ("Power Data.txt");
        for(int x=0; x<=TotalVoltage5s; x++)
        {
         myfile << SavePowerData[x];
         myfile << SaveTimeData[x]; 
        }
        myfile.close();
```

Comment: Did you try opening the file in append mode?

Comment: No, tbh i have not tried yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <fstream>

void append_file(std::string param1,std::string param2, std::string param3){  
  std::ofstream outfile;

  outfile.open("out.txt", std::ios_base::app);
  outfile << param1 << " " << param2<< " " << param3; 
}
```

You can try to encapsulate your method like this and append the values you want to the file each time before putting them to your plot. You can also use a separator just after the end of each 3 params so it will be easier to read from afterwards.

Comment: Do I need another void function to you this method ? Or I can just write the code inside my current function. And another question please, is this way of coding I mean this code  (SaveTimeData[32780] = TotalTime;) correct for saving real time data ?

Comment: You don't need to make another function for it you can just put the code inside your code. If it is a real-time data it means you will keep on getting the data so just putting it in memory all the time , you might run out of memory. I would suggest limiting the amount you store in memory and just showing for example; last 10 mins in graph and saving the older entries in file. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much Yigit, That is what i did and it worked                                             for (int q = 0; q<=TotalTime; q++)
{ 
 Time_[q] = TotalTime;  
 voltage[q] = TotalVoltage5s;
    Frequency[q] = m_frequency;
}

  std::ofstream outfile;

  outfile.open("Power Data.csv", std::ios_base::app);
  outfile<<"Total Time"<<"   "<<"Total Voltage 5 sec"<<"   "<<"Frequency"<<endl; 

  for(int k = 0; k<29; k++){
  outfile << voltage[k]<<", "<<Time_[k]<<", "<<Frequency[k]<<endl; 
  }
 outfile.close();

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Yigit, That is what i did and it worked,

```
for (int q = 0; q<=TotalTime; q++)
{ 
Time_[q] = TotalTime;  
voltage[q] = TotalVoltage5s;
Frequency[q] = m_frequency;}
std::ofstream outfile;
 outfile.open("Power Data.csv", std::ios_base::app);
outfile<<"Total Time"<<"   "<<"Total Voltage 5 sec"<<"   "<<"Frequency"<<endl; 
for(int k = 0; k<TotalTime; k++){outfile<<voltage[k]<<", "<<Time_[k]<<", "<<Frequency[k]<<endl;} 
outfile.close();
```